# Get addLiquidityTransaction on a specific contract on ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, websocket

I'am trying to get an addLiquidityETH event in ethers.js with a WebSocket on a specific contract but got nothing, can someone tell me what am i missing ?

```
const filter = {
address: ' TOKEN ADDRESS ',
topics: [

  // This one below retrieves Transfer TX
  // ethers.utils.id("Transfer(address,address,uint256)")

  // This one does not show liquidity transactions
  ethers.utils.id("addLiquidityETH(address,uint256,uint256,uint256,address,uint256)")
]
}

this.provider.on(filter, (tx) => {
  console.log(tx.transactionHash);
})
```

Any ideas ?